# Iphone/ipad custom controls by touch event

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, user-interaction

I want to create segmented control when the user tap the specific portion of the screen just like the OliveTree bible software application makes it.

When the user tap the verses the app, it automatically shows the segmented controls right above the tap portion or like the copy,select,paste segmented control in iphone.
How to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the `UIMenuController` class. You can use a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to trigger this, and make your class the first responder and setup the `UIMenuController` accordingly.

Here is one example: [UIMenuController Custom Items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537795/uimenucontroller-custom-items)

And here is apple docs: http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UIMenuController_Class/UIMenuController.html