# uimenucontroller in uiwebview with custom menu items without MORE menu

Tags: uiwebview, uimenucontroller, menuitem-selection

In my iPad app, there is a UIWebview that displays text content. When I tap hold and select a text, a menu should popup with 2 custom menu.

say, | MENU1 | MENU2 |

But it seems the COPY menu will also accompany, which I couldn't disable. Is there any possibilities to disable it? I tried around the forum and no solutions worked out.

so itz okay to keep the COPY menu along with the other 2. which should now look like

| Copy | MENU1 | MENU2 |

But unfortunately, I 'm getting it displayed with a MORE menu as follows :

| Copy | More... |

Clicking the More... menu is showing the other 2 menu.

But I need all those 2 items to be displayed in the first attempt itself. either just the 2 menus alone, or atleast along with the copy menu.

| Copy | MENU1 | MENU2 |

OR

| MENU1 | MENU2 |

Get me some solution please.... Trying it out in many ways.. But nothing is working out...
Plz help me out...

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't appear that there is a way to do this without replacing the UIMenuController.  One option is to handle your own UILongPressGestureRecognizer (see [How to remove th COPY UIMenuItem in UIMenuController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262530/how-to-remove-th-copy-uimenuitem-in-uimenucontroller)).  I've seen proposals where you override canPerformAction, but this does not work.  Interestingly, the "copy:" action is never called, though it seems that everything else (cut:,select:,etc.) is.

```
- (BOOL) canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
    if (action == @selector(defineSelection:))
    {
        return YES;
    }
    else if (action == @selector(translateSelection:))
    {
        return YES; 
    }
    else if (action == @selector(copy:))
    {
        return NO;
    }

    return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}
```

`